# Correctly managing a user system

Tags: database

i'm trying to build a platform that would eventually be a web page, android and ios app.

For my platform i want to be able to save data (about user credentials etc..)
I think that the way to do that will be to make a server that contains a db of all the data(?).

I would like to know what is the best way to approach this issue, what is the best way to build such a system (that contains data accessible via the internet) - should i go with SQL? FIREBASE? do i access the db directly? or do i access the server who accesses the db?

I have never worked with databases before, so any information about this would be very helpful, thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think you should start with `sqlite` - it's ubiquitous, available everywhere, embedded in every browser, working on every possible hardware.

Comment: Talk with your ISP or host provider.  The web site provider has database(s) as part of their package.

Comment: thanks, 
@Ingaz, from what i see sqlite is not accessible via network, my goal is to make a user system that a user can enter from every device, and his credentials will be in one accessible place.

Comment: @donPable, i want to build the db myself to learn about it, the website is just hypothetical :)

Comment: If you want multiuser db - my recomendation are: a) postgresql for relational engine, b) redis for non-relation engine. Redis is especially recommended if you really want to "build the db myself to learn"

Comment: Thanks! i will read some more about them